# Why aren't these Empathy bugs fixed? Style broken. First message blank

Tags: empathy

I'm sure this is filed in plenty of bug reports. Does anyone know why on a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 64 and 32bits (and probably several prior releases) this bug in empathy still exists? The first chat message comes in styled like the mess in the screenshot here http://postimg.org/image/jv3ikm3nh/. Getting it right means you need to go into setting, unset the ubuntu theme and reset it. This is such a trashy thing to let linger. Newcomers are instantly turned off.

Plus, the first message received from a sender is not in the new window loaded by empathy. You have to close the message window and open it up again. Really?? Why even have software this crumby loaded? It lowers overall the quality considerably.